# Imagick SVG to JPG - missing jpgs in rendered result

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick

I have some issues in converting svg2jpg with embedded JPGs.
The following code works perfectly on another Server.
Embedded PNGs are working well, only JPGs make troubles.
`

```
    // iterating all image children
    foreach ($xml->xpath('//image') as $image) {
        // fetching the xlink:href attribute
        $xlinkHref = $image->attributes('xlink', TRUE)->href;

        if ($xlinkHref != "") {
            $type = pathinfo($xlinkHref, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

            $data = file_get_contents($xlinkHref);
            $xlinkHref = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data);

            // now setting the new attribute value
            $image->attributes('xlink', TRUE)->href = $xlinkHref;
        }                       
    }
```

ImageMagick Version: 6.7.8-9 2014-06-10 Q16 
(The Code works fine on an older ImageMagick Server with Version: 
6.7.2-7 2013-03-18 Q16)

any ideas?

kind regards

Comment: Imagemagick sometimes get broken when something else is changed. I would install a later version and try that as it is around version 6.9 now. Your versions are about five years old.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the data:image type
"data:image/jpg" did NOT work. Must be specified as "data:image/jpeg" instead.